# Using mulitple layouts in a single slidify slide

Tags: r, slidify

Is it possible to use multiple layouts on a single slide.  I want to use the radio layout and I have a custom made footer layout that I'd like use as well, which puts a logo in the bottom left part of the slide.  To activate the footer I put a footer.html file in the slide deck's `assets/layouts` folder. To reference it I have to write `&footer` after the `---` that creates a new slide.  However to activate the quiz layout I also have to add `&radio` next to the `---` slide.  It won't do both however, for example this doesn't work:

```
---&radio &footer 

## Question 1

What is 1 + 1?

1. 1
2. _2_
3. 3
4. 4

*** .hint
This is a hint

*** .explanation
This is an explanation
```